# How to use cut in R to divide a vector?

Tags: r, cut

I heard I'm supposed to use the cut function in R to divide data into equal parts, but it doesn't seem to be as easy as

```
   which(cut(1:1000,3)==1)
```

My current solution is

```
t<-cut(1:1000,3)
which(match(t,levels(t))==1)
```

I don't believe this to be the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s <- 1:1000
t <- split(s, cut(s, 3))
```

will give you a list with three groups, each having 1/3 of the sequence. Then you would use `t[1]` to get the first group, for instance.